# Swift DispatchQueue is too slow running multiple async

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, dispatch-async

I'd like to run a heavy task in Swift.

So I am trying to use DispatchQueue and run it concurrency.

But It become too slowerwhen I use multiple async().

In this sample, total elapsed time is longer when change 'tasks'  variable bigger.

In Time Profiler, it seems running concurrency.

I guess that Swift might insert some synchronous code automatically.

Do I have to write heavy tasks by Objective-C or C++?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isEnabled = false

    private func calculateSomething(taskCount: Int) {
        print("start")
        let start = Date()
        var c : Int64 = 0
        for _ in 0..<1000000/taskCount {
            c += Int64.random(in: 0..<2)
        }
        let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
        print("end \(c) \(elapsed)")
    }

    private func execute() {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "test", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: .concurrent)

        let start = Date()
        let tasks = 1 // change here
        for _ in 0..<tasks {
            queue.async(group: group) {
                self.calculateSomething(taskCount: tasks)
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
            print("finish: \(elapsed)")
            self.isEnabled.toggle()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap Me") {
            self.execute()
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
        .background(isEnabled ? Color.green : Color.gray)
        .animation(.default)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When 'tasks' is 1.

```
start
end 500115 0.3357279300689697
finish: 0.3377569913864136
```

When 'tasks' is 5

```
start
start
start
start
start
end 99749 1.4837110042572021
end 100203 1.5053819417953491
end 100083 1.5215749740600586
end 100421 1.5263309478759766
end 99923 1.5273290872573853
finish: 1.5298069715499878
```

Comment: i depends how many cores your processor has. normally you should ask the processor how many cores it has and then just build as many threads as number of cores it has. this should be the fastest way.

Answer (score -1):

In your case you shouldn't use `DispatchQueue`. If you will do something concurrent then better to use `OperationQueue`

```swift
func calculateSomething(taskCount: Int) {
    print("start")
    let start = Date()
    var c : Int64 = 0
    for _ in 0 ..< (100000/taskCount) {
        c += Int64.random(in: 0..<2)
    }
    let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
    print("end \(c) \(elapsed)")
}

let taskCount = 4
let start = Date()
let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
operationQueue.name = "test"
operationQueue.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 20

operationQueue.addOperations((0 ..< taskCount).map { _ in BlockOperation {
    calculateSomething(taskCount: taskCount)
}}, waitUntilFinished: true)
operationQueue.addBarrierBlock {
    let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
    print("finish: \(elapsed)")
}
```

- 1 tasks -> `// finish: 2.910871982574463`
- 2 tasks -> `// finish: 1.5314499139785767`
- 4 tasks -> `// finish: 1.1279020309448242`
- 6 tasks -> `// finish: 0.8491430282592773`
- 8 tasks -> `// finish: 0.7050379514694214`

Comment: Thank you for reply and code.

But among using your sample, taskCount 1 is faster than 2 or above.

Comment: Look at my results, `taskCount` 1 is slower than 2 or above

Comment: Yes, your results is natural and my results should be like it.
I attached my results in new answer.